# Why querySelector returns null when I used the defer attribute?

Tags: javascript, select

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testHtml</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<script  src="testCode.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>butt1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
. red {background-color:red;}
```

JS

```
let butt1 = document.querySelector("button");
butt1. classList. add("red");
```

This code produces an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

I understand that `querySelector` in this returns a `null` or `undefined` value, therefore it does not have any properties. But the button element is clearly on the page and I am using the `defer` attribute.

What may cause such behavior?

Comment: But does the "defer" flag not postpone the script until DOM is loaded?

Comment: Actually, with `defer`, I cannot reproduce this behaviour. I created a page with the exact same content, and it found the button. Please provide more information and a reproducible example.

Comment: It works as expected with `defer`. Are you sure your browser is loading the latest version of the file?

Comment: To be sure, wrap it in window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { /* your code here */ }); to make sure the DOM elements are present. That way you can have the code inline or remove the defer

Comment: It's working fine for me, maybe try changing your browser or check if the browser is updated or not.

Comment: @AnshalPatel the `defer` attribute is supported in all major browsers since about 2010. So unless OP is using a timemachine it's quite unlikely that the alledged error happens because of missing browser support

Comment: I'm using a free Android environment. I guess I'll have to postpone my hands on learning till I get to the real machine.